# Handling arbitrary arguments portably in AWK

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, posix

I want to make my *shebang* enabled POSIX **awk** programs have more of a standard interface to them -- not using the -v var=val interface but using one that looks like other programs available from the Linux/UNIX command line.  The issue that I have encountered is that **awk** scripts relay flags to awk -- and then awk itself has first crack at interpreting those flags.  Also, different implementations of **awk** have different flag options.  The end result is that it is nigh impossible to build an **awk** program with an interface that can just work parsing ARGC, ARGV[] for flags.

So, I end up encapsulating my **awk** programs in shell -- which adds to my support and testing burden -- and that shell code looks like the following:

```
arg_core=""
arg_directory=""
arg_module=""
arg_output=""
arg_regmap=""
arg_regpage=""
arg_help=0
arg_version=0
arg_verbose=0
while getopts c:d:m:o:p:r:hvV o
do
        case "$o" in
        c) arg_core="$OPTARG";;
        d) arg_directory="$OPTARG";;
        m) arg_module="$OPTARG";;
        o) arg_output="$OPTARG";;
        p) arg_regpage="$OPTARG";;
        r) arg_regmap="$OPTARG";;
        h) arg_help=1;;
        v) arg_version=1;;
        V) arg_verbose=1;;
        --) break;;
        ?) help >&2
             exit 1;;
        esac
done
shift `expr $OPTIND - 1`

# Handling help and version (verbose option also displays revision
# history and notes) is more easily done outside the getopts loop.
if [ $arg_version -gt 0 ]
then
        version
        [ $arg_verbose -gt 0 ] && rev_history
fi
if [ $arg_help -gt 0 ]
then
        [ $arg_version -gt 0 ] && echo
        help
fi
[ $arg_help -gt 0 -o $arg_version -gt 0 ] && exit 0

awk -v arg_core="$arg_core" -v arg_directory="$arg_directory" -v arg_module="$arg_module" -v arg_output="$arg_output" -v arg_regmap="$arg_regmap" -v arg_regpage="$arg_regpage" -f rffe2tpf.awk -- "$@"
```

My question is... I want to eliminate the shell script encapsulation and want to do my argument parsing in **awk** -- and I want to do it *portably*.  (Note... I am not asking, "How do I do getopts in **awk**?"  I am instead asking, "How do I *from the shebang* in an **awk** script portably stop **awk** from parsing flags?")  Is there a way to trick **awk** or the shebang into accomplishing this goal?

Comment: GNU awk does [have a `getop` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getopt-Function.html). Is that what you need?

Comment: @BinaryZebra -- *portable* to me means that I want to be POSIX compliant.  For the present, I want the option to use either gawk or mawk... and I also want my scripts to be relatively future-proof.

Comment: An awk getopt from not-gnu is not available AFAIK. A [POSIX getopts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) only exists for shell scripts. You are in for a world of hurt. Good luck.

Comment: This is why I use perl

Comment: **@BinaryZebra** -- Thank you for one thing -- the getopt.awk that GNU awk places in /usr/share/awk (at least on Ubuntu and Suse) does look like POSIX awk and is released in the public domain; so, perhaps this could be /part/ of the solution... The issue for me is portably stopping POSIX awk from parsing arguments from the shebang (if possible).  **@Niel** -- perl has proven too slow for my use, and is not POSIX. Thank you for the suggestion, but perl does not fit my need.

Comment: I do not understand why the automatic response to GNU of: "is not POSIX", when, in fact, there is a lot of POSIX compliance effort in most of the programs. Well, I guess that is one of the unsolved mysteries of the Universe.

Comment: @BinaryZebra -- I am no GNU, but... Someone could conceivably build a system without perl and do just fine -- or perl7 could just start from scratch and rewrite everything.  POSIX compliance is pretty much a given (or a good guess?) as a base going forward in a UNIX-like system, and as awk is specified as a POSIX utility, it's as good a bet as any that it will both be around and support the same syntax as we have in today's standard for the next 50-100 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting to stackoverflow has made me think more deeply about the problem, and I believe I have something closer to a solution.  If anyone has some "shebang-foo" that I am unaware of that can solve this problem, then I will pick that answer above my own.

Special thanks to **BinaryZebra** for pointing me to **getopt.awk** -- as I no longer need to think about rolling my own getopt() implementation.

We may not be able to portably provide the behaviour we want from the shebang, but we are able to significantly limit the amount of code in the shell script to support the behaviour we want. The proposed solution is generic and can be used for all our **awk** scripts.

I call the following script **bawk**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
p=$1
shift
awk -f "$p" -- "$@"
```

If **bawk** is placed in our path, it can be used in the awk script's shebang.  Here is a test script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bawk
BEGIN { for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) print ARGV[i] }
```

Output:

```
$ ./foo.awk -abc -1 -2 -3
-abc
-1
-2
-3
```